# How to debug LDAP addressbook connection in Evolution

Tags: evolution, ldap

When searching an address book on an active directory I get the error:

`Cannot get contact list: LDAP error 0x1 (Operations error)`

how can I get more detailed information?

Answer (score 3):

The addressbook component of evolution has to be started in the debug mode.
For this we will kill the whole evolution processes first:

In a terminal:

```
pkill evolution
export LDAP_DEBUG=1
/usr/lib/evolution/evolution-addressbook-factory -r
```

No evolution can be started as normal and in the first opened terminal we will see detailed information on the LDAP communication.

Comment: This doens't work any more, does it?